# Populating a table with ng-repeat and conditionals

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I am fairly new to angular (2 weeks old), and I am having trouble understanding the proper implementation of a table, populated with data that is derived from the `$scope`.

To be more specific. I have a table that I am populating with a hardcoded array of times (i.e. `[{ "time": "8:00 - 8 - 30"},...`):

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Contact Person</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="time in times" style="cursor:pointer">
        <td> {{time.time}}
       </td>
          <td>

              <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" ng-click="open(time.time)">Open</button>

          </td>
          <td>---</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

I have another `$scope` element with an array of objects called `$scope.reservations`. The data in the model looks like this:

[image: The Console output of $scope.reservations]

What I am attempting to do is put a conditional in the second column (status) where if the `$scope.reservations.timeSlot == {{time.time}}`, then display a specific `div` (in this case, the `div` would say "this space is already taken). else, continue with displaying the button labeled "Open".

This conditional would also be used in the next column (contact person), where if `$scope.reservations.timeSlot == {{time.time}}`, then display a `div` with `$scope.reservations.NetID`. else, continue with displaying "---".

I know that I somehow have to nest a `ng-repeat` with another `ng-repeat`, and possibly a `ng-show`? but I am struggling with wrapping my head about the proper syntax to accomplish this. Would anyone know the best way to accomplish populating such a table?

UPDATE: here is a plunker I created to reproduce the problem: [example Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nIJzgJ7JgyAvIeLYiX8i?p=preview)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and if you have any questions or concerns for me, please do not hesitate to ask. I want to be able to implement this, and actually understand what is going on. I hope you are all having a good day!

Comment: It feels to me like you have too much information in the client side.
confirmationCode shouldn't be on the client side unless you want to present it (which doesn't sound right by your description)

Comment: a plnkr is always good to help to reproduce and also illustrate your problem in a more concise manner

Comment: @Yaron U. you are correct, at the moment I have too much information in the $scope.reservations. I have the info coming from a mongodb, and havnt added a projection on the db.collection.find() fetch yet. I will slim down the amount of data returned once I can properly display it, and weed out what I wont need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best solution in your case would be manipulating the data that you received, before you present it (either when you get it from the server or on the server before it is being sent to the client)

If your data looked like this:

```
$scope.times = [{
   "time": "8:00-8:30",
   "reservation":null
},{
   "time": "8:00-8:30",
   "reservation": {
       "_NetId": "1234567"
   }
}]
```

Then you could do something like

```
...
  <tr ng-repeat="time in times" style="cursor:pointer">
    <td> {{time.time}}
   </td>
      <td>

          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" ng-click="open(time.time)">Open</button>

      </td>
      <td>
         <span ng-if="!time.reservation">---</span>
         <span ng-if="!!time.reservation">{{time.reservation.NetId}}</span>
      </td>
  </tr>
...
```

Comment: I agree that it would be easier if I coupled the Times table data with the actual reservation data. 

This application will eventually incorporate socket.io. given that knowledge, do you think with your solution, it would be best to do that type of data formating in, maybe a angularjs Service, then pushing to the client (as you have demonstrated here) ? I just want to make sure I am going about this the best way possible where I know frequent updates will happen.

Comment: a) You have your controller, where you hold the `$scope` - you can use it to format the data.

b) socket.io doesn't change anything.

c) If I do it, I'd probably change the data back in the server before it is being sent to the client

Comment: U I have tried your advice, but ended up having to revert back to decoupling the `times` from the actual reservation. Although it wasnt mentioned above, there are multiple rooms for reservations. What ended up happening is if the room was switched from room A to room B, then room B would also display all the 'reserved' spots from room A. I imagine it is because the $scope.times is shared amongst all the rooms. the work around would be to reset the $scope.times data every time I change rooms, but that seems like a lot if this conditional formatting can be handled with directives.

Comment: So you should put `times` inside `room` (e.g. `room.times.reservation`) - that also makes more since from the business logic side - if you would want to allow different times for different rooms in the future

Comment: That is a good idea! It does raise a few other questions though that, I believe, is outside the scope of this particular SO topic. I will accept your answer as the correct one, but would you be willing to chat with me for a few minutes concerning design? I feel like you know what you are doing, and can provide a straight answer to my follow-up question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$index` with `ng-repeat` to use the respective object from `reservation` array.

And, use `ng-show`/`ng-hide` to show/hide if `$scope.reservations.timeSlot == {{time.time}}` or not, and similar results.

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Contact Person</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="time in times" style="cursor:pointer">
        <td> {{time.time}}
       </td>
          <td>
              <div ng-show="reservations[$index].timeSlot == time.time">Already Taken</div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" ng-click="open(time.time)" ng-hide="reservations[$index].timeSlot == time.time">Open</button>

          </td>
          <td>
               <div ng-show="reservations[$index].timeSlot == time.time">{{reservation[$index].netID}}</div>
               <div ng-hide="reservations[$index].timeSlot == time.time">---</div> 
          </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: I like this solution, but it doesnt seem to traverse fully through the $scope.reservations array of objects. It DOES work for the first timeslot, but any other reservation made at a different time get updated. would i need to put a ng-repeat anywhere to get each "time" to look at all of the $scope.reservations objects and check their .timeSlot?

Comment: `reservation[$index]` is going through the reservation array.  So it should do the trick.

Comment: This doesnt seem to loop through each `reservation` object in the `reservations` array. whatever mechanism that loops over each row would need to similarly to a `angular.forEach(reservations)`, and compare 1 `time` to all the `reservation.timeSlot` 's in the `reservations` array. I made a Plunker, if that helps to demonstrate. 

[link to Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nIJzgJ7JgyAvIeLYiX8i?p=preview)